# PHP: Reload Bootstrap modal form if errors are detected in inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

My problem is that when I click the submit button the modal closes and the only way to know if an error has trigerred is if I click again on the button to make the modal form appear. The error trigger works fine but I would like to reload the modal window if an error is detected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the button to trigger the modal form and the form div:

```
<button id="addFilm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-5 mr-3" data- toggle="modal" data-target="#modalFilm">
Add a film
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalFilm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
  aria-hidden="true">
```

Here's a function that checks if an input is empty and then triggers an error message right below the input title:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['code'])){ 
        if($_GET['code'] == 'addFilm'){ 
           if (!Utilitaire::validateInput($_POST['title'])) {
            echo ("Please enter a title");
             $validate= false;

           }
        } 
      } 
?>
```

Comment: do it with ajax or open the modal via js after page load

Answer (score 1):

you can programmatically open modal if you need

```
<?php if (!$validate) : ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#modalFilm').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#via-javascript

Comment: So it seems I really can't do what I want without using Ajax because the submit button even with added conditions will always refresh the page of origin... I need to POST the input values, run them through my validators and pop up again if there's an error or stay closed and do the INSERT in the db. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: you can prevent form submitting and manipulate the modal popup after validating your data, when you got response